# How to call the Js Function on onload event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hi i am using accordians div in my web page for this i am using this code.

```
/*****************js part ************/


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li#sencondlink").click(function(){
        $("#secondlinkContent").slideToggle("slow").siblings(".accordionContent").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("myCurrentItemStyle");
        $(this).siblings(".links").removeClass("myCurrentItemStyle");
   });
});

/*****************HTML part ************/

<div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="accordionLinks">
        <ul>
            <li class="links" id="sencondlink"><font color="#000000" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;RDSM</i></b></font>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="accordionContainer">
        <div class="accordionContent" id="secondlinkContent">
            JEO<br>Peter<br>john
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

the above code is working fine .The accordian div working in click event but i want to show the accordian div on window onload event. if change the code ,

```
 $("li#sencondlink").window.onload(function(){
```

it does not work , it dont give any error , how to i call the function in onload event plz guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `$(document).ready(function(){ ... }` to `$(window).load(function(){ ... }`

Comment: It is possible to call the function on window.onunload event

Comment: @Meena No, as the effect won't ever be seen. You can only interrupt that event with a blocking action (such as `alert()` or `confirm()`).